# Split only first group of string with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to search for a specific string can anyone tell me why I am seeing below result?
I checked it out in an Online regex site, It seems I have seperated in to 3 groups and now the result is printing the 3 groups. how I can only seperate the first group?

Also is it possible to change the code so the "String" with lower case would be detected?

Relative String

```
DD-JSH-String43423213-3774
DE-String43423214-SDC-3721
```

Output:

```
'String43423213', 'String', '43423213','String43423214', 'String', '43423214'
```

Code:

```
matches = re.findall(r'((String)(\d+))', inp)
matches = [j for sub in matches for j in sub if j != ""]
```

Expected Result:

```
'String43423213', 'String43423214'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are even grouping on the two matches, so you have to remove the outer group. And also you can add flag `re.I` to ignore case:

```
matches = re.findall(r'(String)(\d+)', inp, flags=re.I)
print(*[''.join(x) for x in matches],sep="\n")
```

Comment: I just run this code: The result is seperating and the result is: 'String','43423214' , however i want it in this format String43423214

Comment: Check out the edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this [regex-demo](https://regex101.com/r/mrVK7Z/2/):

**python source:**

```
input="""DD-JSH-String43423213-3774
DE-String43423214-SDC-3721"""
```

```
matches = re.findall(r'String\d+', input, flags=re.I)
print(matches)
```

or

```
matches = re.findall(r'(?i)String\d+', input)
print(matches)
```

**output:**

```
['String43423213', 'String43423214']
```

**explanation:**
Because your regex has two groups `String` and `\d+`, **re.findall** returns a list that contains all tuples of the two groups like `('String', 'String43423214')`. You could group it like `(String\d+)` or non-group like `String\d+`, both expressions are working.

Answer (score -2):

you can do this:

```
import re
inp = """
DD-JSH-String43423213-3774
DE-String43423214-SDC-3721
"""
matches = matches = re.findall(r'String\d+', inp)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```